# SQL to select and swap id columns so parameter appears in left hand column

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm looking to put together an SQL query for a matrix-like table to select a certain value (which can appear in either column) and then switch the id columns so that the search value always appears on the left hand side.

I'm having trouble explaining it coherently to search for an answer, but here's an example:

**DB Table**

```
id1 | id2 | value
----|-----|-------
 1  |  4  |  0.2
 2  |  1  |  0.3
 3  |  1  |  0.5
 2  |  3  |  0.1
```

**Desired output if I'm looking for value 1, note the last two columns switching position:**

```
id1 | id2 | value
----|-----|-------
 1  |  4  |  0.2
 1  |  2  |  0.3   
 1  |  3  |  0.5
```

My current SQL is as follows:

```
SELECT (id1, id2, value) FROM db-table WHERE 1 in (id1, id2);
```

Which gets the correct values, but without swapping. The result is:

```
id1 | id2 | value
----|-----|-------
 1  |  4  |  0.2
 2  |  1  |  0.3   
 3  |  1  |  0.5
```

I'm using sqlite3 but I can translate/fix domain specific issues if someone is able to point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the below query. Its working fine.

**create and insert values**

```
create table #table1
(
   id1 int,
   id2 int,
   val nvarchar(20)
)

insert into #table1 values (1,4,0.2);
insert into #table1 values (2,1,0.3);
insert into #table1 values (3,1,0.5);
insert into #table1 values (2,3,0.1);
```

**write below query to get result**

```
select * from (
                 SELECT id1 ,id2, val FROM #table1 where id1 = 1
                 union 
                 SELECT id2 ,id1, val from #table1 where id2 = 1
              ) t 
order by t.val asc
```

**here we go with the output.**

[image]

~ cheers

Comment: looks good, thanks. I think two selects and a union may be slower than Gordon's answer, however

Comment: in practice I've found your answer to be faster than the others. Accepting yours instead

Comment: @mbdavis . . . Which is faster and which is slower depends on the data.   My version does a full table scan and a sort.  With indexes on each column, this will reduce the size of the data and not do a full table scan.  It does incur additional overhead for removing duplicates, but that would be on a smaller data volume.  Which is faster depends on a lot of factors.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes - with indexes. My dataset is huge, and I can't see a way to index so that yours completes in a fast time - it's taking around a minute. With indexes I can run this one almost instantly. Open to suggestions on index to make yours complete faster

Comment: @mbdavis . . . In SQLite there isn't a way, and this is the better solution for your situation.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
select 1 as id1,
       (case when id1 = 1 then id2 else id1 end) as id2,
       value
from t
where 1 in (id1, id2)
order by value;
```

Comment: Accepting as I believe this is the most performant against the other answers. Thanks!

Comment: In practice I have found this to be slower than @Manoj Bhardwaj's answer

Comment: @mbdavis . . . Interesting.  That would be true if you have indexes on each column.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want,

```
Select IIF(id1<=id2,id1,id2) id1, iif(id1>id2,id1,id2) id2,value
From table
```

If `IIF` not valid in `SQLite` try `CASE` statement.

```
Select case when id1<=id2 then id1 else id2 end id1,
       Case when id1>id2  then id1 else id2 end id2
From table
Where 1 in (id1,id2)
```

Comment: 1) It should be fairly easy for you to verify if `IIF` is a sqlite expression and 2) It's not an ANSI sql expression; you'd be better off answering using ANSI standard SQL where possible

Comment: He asked for an idea, I'm sitting on my couch. Again another reason to give up helping, when all u get is ridicule

Comment: I do most of my posting from an iphone, which makes SQLs a bitch to type, but I still google occasionally to make sure what I'm answering. Ideas should be put in comments. Answers are supposed to be correct/factual, not "well try X but maybe sqlite doesnt have X, i don't know, and can't be bothered to check. But VB6 has it!" :/ DOn't get me wrong; i too hate the way SO is a bitch-fest of pros all seemingly trying to be massive dicks to each other and I take breaks from it for the same reason; i'm just pointing out that what you've posited as an answer here, isn't answer because it's broken

Comment: Ab - thanks, I'll give it a go! @CaiusJard I see what you're saying but work on your tone - I've already mentioned in my question I'm happy to work with any sql standard

Comment: @mbdavis you too, are missing the point of stack overflow. SO is for factual questions and factual answers. If someone wants to post something in the "i dunno if it'll work - try it, but it might not, and though it's easy to check, i haven't bothered" style, then it's a comment, NOT an answer. It's the digital equivalent of littering; these questions and answeres aren't jsut about you, or him, or me.. Theyre about the possibly thousands of others who will come later. This answer is broken, and should be deleted to save others being misled

Comment: @CaiusJard the point is for people to get answers - realistically this question will get at most 3/4 answers and then the community can decide which are the most useful through voting and accepting. If someone else stumbles across my non db engine specific question and leaves with a query involving IIF that meets their needs then great - it's saved the e-litter of them asking the question again. Worst case here, someone loses out on a scroll. Low quality questions are more worth your moderation energy than a well meaning answer. Anyway - last I'll reply on the subject

Comment: The bloke asked for help, if no one else could answer him, what I gave him may be enuf for him to solve the rest. But with arm chair warriors like yourself you are encouraging no one to help. One day you may have a problem someone can only answer in a slight variant of syntax but it's enuf to get you by.

Comment: @AbBennett "And yet the query you wrote is wrong" -  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/f6d9c/1 - oh look, it works. Yawn. Don't hate just because a) you can't understand it, b) you have no idea what you're talking about and your answer is a waste of mbdavis' time and c) you only posted something that had a chance of working after several other people did - hmm, I wonder how you "worked out" your revised version..

Comment: Well your first attempt at answering didn't include it so it's a fair bet it was until you pulled out good old google! lol

Comment: This conversation has made my morning... but the logic is wrong on both of your answers! I need the search value on the left, not the minimum! See Gordons answer

Answer (score -1):

You mean something more like:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
 SELECT 
  CASE WHEN id1 < id2 THEN id1 ELSE id2 END as id1,
  CASE WHEN id1 < id2 THEN id2 ELSE id1 END as id2,
  value
 FROM db-table 
) a
WHERE id1 = 1
ORDER BY value
```

Comment: No need to wrap this, it solves nothing. You may be doing 99 million case calculations just filter them out

Comment: You've clearly no idea how query optimizers work then, but carry on being the hypocrite - complaining that you're getting bitched at and then immediately going and finding someone to carry out some revenge bitching on.. :) Oh, and now revenge downvoting.. Gosh, you're a model of maturity. Do  please make good on your threat to quit stackoverflow at some point..

Comment: What's the purpose of the redundant wrapper, its pointless code. Why not put another one around it

Comment: Put 1 in (id1,id2)

Comment: Pretty sure I don't need query writing advice from someone who doesnt know the difference between VB6 and SQLite, thanks

Comment: what the hell are u on about, ur wrapper looks like a 5 year olds work

Comment: @CaiusJard thanks for the answer - I believe the logic is wrong though. It holds for the example table, but I need the query value to appear on the left, not the lowest of the two values